# Delete a file from a given folder N days old

Tags: vbscript

I have written a script that calls for two parameters but every time I run I receive an error message:

> Line: 7 Char: 21 Error: Expected Literal constant Code: 800A0415

Can some one please help me understand what I am doing wrong here?

The script below is expecting to receive 2 parameters and execute a file deletion based upon those parameters.

The first parameter will contain the path to the file(s) to be deleted, the second parameter will contain a number representing days old.

```
Dim arg, var1, var2
set arg = wscript.Arguments
var1 = arg(0)
var2 = arg(1)

Const strPath = var1
Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Call Search (strPath)
WScript.Echo"Completed Successfully."

Sub Search(str)
    Dim objFolder, objSubFolder, objFile
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(str)
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If objFile.DateLastModified < (Now() - var2) Then
            objFile.Delete(True)
        End If
    Next
    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
        Search(objSubFolder.Path)
    Next
End Sub
Set objFSO = nothing
Set arg = nothing
```

Comment: `but every time I run I receive an error message` -- and that error message would be... ?  And it occurs on line... ?

Comment: You should rename the question to something that is more indicative of the specific problem. Please also try to clarify by specifying the exact nature of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the following line:

```
Const strPath = var1
```

You cannot set the value of a constant to be a variable. You need to explicitly state a literal thing to be a constant, like:

```
Const strPath = "C:\Some\Path"
```

Given what you are trying to do, you would be better off using strPath as a variable and going from there.

```
Dim strPath : strPath = var1
```

Or some other similar solution.